# A Question From Measure Theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

How to show that a basis for the vector space $\mathbb{R}$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}$ is not Lebesgue measurable? Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://www.imsc.res.in/~sunder/mgnvss.pdf

Comment: It can be constructed from a measure-zero set.